# PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "PROMPT"

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I need to deploy database objects by calling a script. But it throws an error like this "PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "PROMPT" ".

What could be the problem with my script? 
My script is as follows:

```
set echo on
spool logs/dm_ref.log
Prompt Running dw/deploy/dm_ref/file.sql...
@dw/deploy/dm_ref/file.sql

Prompt Running dw/deploy/dm_ref/file_tbl.sql...
@dw/deploy/dm_ref/file_tbl.sql

spool off
set echo off
```

the 2nd Prompt is for creating a table which successfully runs. 
The problem is with the first Prompt for which it creates a stored procedure.

Thank's in advance.

Comment: the issue could be in the scipts you're running; for example, maybe you're missing the ending `/` after a plsql block

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is you're not giving us enough information to answer your question.

SQL Developer's script engine DOES support the PROMPT command.

[image]

Please amend your question to include the spooled output, the error message, and the contents of your .sql files you are executing.